# Spring MVC application not responding for more than 1 request

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have spring mvc based application which has one UI page through which we handle quartz jobs. means this UI page has all quartz job listing, last run status and hyperlinks in the row of each job to start a particular job. When user will clink on this hyperlink, request goes to server and according that job gets triggered. When that job gets completed, controller send backs the response which will get reflected on the UI. Everything is working fine in this UI. But when user want to open any other link or page in our web application, nothing is happening....means browser shows progress but at last it does not go to any page. We are expecting that user can visit any page and when again user will come at this quartz job page, it should get what ever it has.

I am not able to understand why this is happening because in web application, many request can be send at a time. So why my application is not responding it. Any pointer in this regard will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Thanks,

Gopal Lal

Comment: If you want to handle asynchronous requests, I suggest you use AJAX to execute your quartz trigger so that it gets processed in the background.

Comment: A webrequest should never be blocked waiting for completion of a task. It should return immediately and user would poll to see progress. This polling can be automatic through AJAX or simply a meta tag `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="..."> in header.

Comment: Already I am making an ajax call using $.getJSON() method. But still I am facing the same issue. Any other thing I should check in my code?

Comment: As per my investigation,  $.getJSON() send http get request, not ajax call. Please let me know if this is the problem.

Comment: to make ajax call on server, I have used $.ajax() method also. But I am still facing this issue means I am not able to open other page until the job quartz job get done and server send response. So please let me know what other things I should check.